# Width and length price calculator help (adding options) using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I have a problem with my price calculator when I've tried to add options

(JS Fiddle here = http://jsfiddle.net/wemdragon/hXydV/)

What I'm trying to do is where it says:

```
var firstoption=$('select#myselect')
```

I would like the options value turned into a price value like:

```
option value (which is 1)  = 20.00
```

but I can't seem to do it.  If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably give the `<option>` the values you want, then just use:

```
var firstOption = +$('select#myselect').val();
```

jQuery `val()` grabs the selected value, and the `+` converts the string value (like `"20"`) to a numeric.